# Ax.plot() is not plotting my buy/sell marker

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please see the code in Google Colab notebook,

I don’t know if I have wrong condition in the plotting or something, but I just can not get marker of buy/sell signal to be printed out in the plot.

```
#Import the libraries
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
print("Setup Complete")
```

```
#Create a function to calculate the Keltner Channel
def keltner_channels(data, window=20, atr_multiplier=1):

  #Create am empty dictionary
  keltner_channels = {}

  #Calculate the typical price
  typical_price = (data['High'] + data['Low'] + data['Close']) / 3

  #Calculate the exponential moving average
  exponential_movin_average = typical_price.ewm(span=window, adjust =False).mean()

  #Calculate the Average True Range (ATR)
  true_range = np.maximum(data['High'] - data['Low'], np.maximum(abs(data['High'] - exponential_movin_average), abs(data['Low'] - exponential_movin_average)))
  average_true_range = true_range.ewm(span=window, adjust=False).mean()

  #Calculate teh Keltner Channel Upper and Lower Band
  keltner_channels['upper'] = exponential_movin_average + atr_multiplier * average_true_range
  keltner_channels['lower'] = exponential_movin_average - atr_multiplier * average_true_range

  #Calculate the Keltner Channel Middle Band
  keltner_channels['middle'] = exponential_movin_average

  return keltner_channels
```

```
#Create a function to plot the Keltner Channel
def plot_keltner_channel(data, keltner_channels):

  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 6))

  #Plot the data
  ax.plot(data.index, data['Close'], label = 'Close')

  #Plot the Keltner Channel Upper, Lower, and Middle bands
  ax.plot(keltner_channels['upper'], label='Upper Band')
  ax.plot(keltner_channels['lower'], label='Lower Band')
  ax.plot(keltner_channels['middle'], label='Middle Band')


  #Shade the area between the bands
  ax.fill_between(keltner_channels['upper'].index, keltner_channels['upper'], keltner_channels['lower'], color='grey', alpha=0.5)


  #Plot the buy and sell signals
  crossed = False #if the Close Price had crossed the upper band/lower band

  buy_signal_number = 0
  sell_signal_number = 0

  buy_signal_restraint = 1
  sell_signal_restraint = 1

  for i in range(len(data)):
    if data['Close'].iloc[i] < keltner_channels['lower'].iloc[i]:
      buy_signal_number += 1
      sell_signal_number = 0
      if (buy_signal_number >= buy_signal_restraint) and crossed == False:
        ax.plot(data.index[i], data['Close'].iloc[i], marker = '^', markersize = 10, color = 'green')
        crossed = True
        buy_signal_number = 0

    elif data['Close'].iloc[i] > keltner_channels['upper'].iloc[i]:
      sell_signal_number += 1
      buy_signal_number = 0
      if (sell_signal_number >= sell_signal_restraint) and crossed == True:
        ax.plot(data.index[i], data['Close'].iloc[i], marker = 'v', markersize = 10, color = 'red')
        crossed = False
        sell_signal_number = 0


    #Format the plot
    ax.set_title("Keltner Channels ")
    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Price')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

```
#Read in the data
data = yf.download('AAPL', start='2023-01-01', end='2023-03-31')
data = df.reset_index(data)
data
```

```
#Get the Keltner Channels
keltner_channels = keltner_channels(data, window=20, atr_multiplier=1)

print(keltner_channels) #Which seems okay
```

```
#plot the data and the Keltner Channel
plot_keltner_channel(data, keltner_channels)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lGOY.png)

I have check both keltner channel function and plotting function but I can not find a bug.

Comment: Have you checked whether you enter the `if` statements?

Comment: Hi! I have tested your code, and as @jared suggested, you never enter the `if` condition where the markers are added. The reason is that you just cross the upper boundary, i.e. you just enter your `elif` condition. However, you never enter in the inner `if` as you set `crossed = False` and it is never changed throughout the whole `for` loop.

Maybe you could give some more hints about the logic behind your `if` statements and the intended function of the `crossed` flag, if you want further help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my previous comment, if you completely remove the condition on the `crossed` flag, you can get to print a buy or sell sign when you are below or above the channels.

[image: Kelter channels with sell signs]

Please note that in order for your marker to be shown, you have to use `fig.show()` rather than `plt.show()` as the last command in your working function.

Again, the one shown in the picture is probably not the plot you were looking for. I just wanted to show you that you will get some markers plotted if you:

- remove the `crossed` flag, thus entering the inner `if` condition
- change `plt.show()` to `fig.show()`

If you still have problems with the logic you want to implement, try to improve the description of the expected result in your question.

Comment: Thanks Luca, it helps a lot. And problem solved with the crossed flag removed.